# Proper way of writing Methods / Routines that don't return values in Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I'm trying to define a Method (or routine) that do not return any value, inside a class.

```
function _class()
{
  this.function _classMethod(){}
}
```

It gives me an `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` at the line `_classMethod()` is defined.

I'm aware that I can write methods like this-

```
function _class()
{
  this._classMethod = function(){}
}
```

And this actually works.

But in my case, `_classMethod()` has nothing to return. It's just supposed to get objects by reference and do it's stuff.

<s>Any better / alternate way of achieving what I want here?</s>

I was mistaken about the way functions in JavaScript works. The regular style suits my needs.

Comment: The assignment has nothing to do with whether the function returns anything. It's giving a name to the function, not assigning its result.

Comment: If a function doesn't returning anything, just leave out the `return` statement in the function body.

Comment: This kind of question should be posted to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Javascript functions always return something wether you do it explicitly with return statement or not, in the second case undefined is returned;

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.The usual style of defining function seems to be the best way to achieve what I want.